# Yammer unauthorized error despite having valid yammer token

Tags: authentication, oauth, yammer

We receive loads of Yammer unauthorized exceptions for hundreds or more of our users despite those users having authenticated with Oauth and us storing the auth token.

This has been happening for months.

As far as I'm aware, Yammer oauth tokens do not expire and the only way we should get an unauthenticated error once a user has authenticated is if they revoked the token through yammer. However, its incredibly dubious that hundreds of users would all be revoking simultaneously in the fashion we are seeing.

Is there something else I'm missing? Could an entire network revoke authentications for their users?

Any help in figuring this out is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The tokens are generally long lived but they do expire. There isn't a set lifespan for them.

From https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/oauth-2

> Once the token expires, you will need to re-run the steps above to generate a new code and access_token. If the user has already authorized your app they will not be prompted to do so again.

Users can of course revoke access to applications individually, but a verified admin can also disable 3rd party apps (which will prevent further generation of tokens on behalf of any users) and technically, should that org wish, a verified admin account could impersonate users and then revoke apps which have been already authorized (because of a change in security policy etc).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Naomi! I thought I remember Yammer's dev docs saying that tokens never expire, but that was before they've done their recent revamp of the whole developer site and documentation.

Comment: I'd like to note that today we received about 10 exceptions from 10 users in a single company all within about a minute of each other. This is a company we work with and I"m positive they did not disable 3rd party apps. Why would this happen?

Comment: Good question. There's very little info from Yammer on the generation of the auth token. One potential source is that recently MSFT has been rolling out simplified SSO which means the user will use their O365 login credentials to also access Yammer. In which case all users affected (anyone using O365 that didn't already have ADFS/DSync in process) will have to reauthorize a Yammer app. The update required for JS Origins in Yammer apps could also potentially affect the ability to generate a token on the app side (http://naomimoneypenny.com/2015/02/11/yammer-apps-javascript-origins-update/)